# How to reset tableViewCell's content in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create custom cell and for some cell I add new subView:

```
  static NSString *cellIdentifierCell = @"Cell";

FeedCell *cell = (FeedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierCell];
if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[FeedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierCell]; //frame
}

 //here add subView

     if (wallPost.attachmentLinks[@"audio"])
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    [cell addAudio:wallPost.attachmentLinks[@"audio"] fromStartFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50 + collectionHeight + 5 + 90 + 5, 300, 20)];
   } else {
    for (UIView *v in cell.subviews)    //// (1)
    {
        if (v.tag == 333)
        {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the cell method I use:

```
 - (void)addAudio:(NSArray *)arrayAudio fromStartFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
for (NSDictionary *dic in arrayAudio)
 {
    UIView *audioView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    audioView.frame = CGRectMake(10, frame.origin.y-100, 300, 20);
    audioView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    audioView.tag = 333;
    [self addSubview:audioView];

}
[self layoutSubviews];
 }
```

Problem is that I have subViews in cells that must not have it. Part (1) does not run. How can I reset cell or delete custom View from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you create two cell views. Its not best approach to remove views by using tags. on else portion of your code, just use alternate view that will give look as empty view. It may be the alternate approach to handle the situation.

Comment: hello, yep, it works! with this approach I do not need to remove old view anywhere, right?

Comment: But I do not add zeroView, I make layoutSubviews

Comment: @user3521459 yes; no need to remove old view. Because at a time you are using any one view. views will be automatically changed as you will call [tableView reload] method.

Comment: ---views will be automatically changed as you will call [tableView reload] method - is it ok?

Comment: you need to do like: [cell addAudio:YOUR_APP_DATA isEmptyView:YES/NO];
addAudio method will take decision, which view should be load on the basis of bool value.

Answer (score 0):

You should always remove the old view, before adding the new view. So the code should look like this

```
for (UIView *v in cell.subviews)    //// (1)
{
    if (v.tag == 333)
        [v removeFromSuperview];
}

if (wallPost.attachmentLinks[@"audio"])
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    [cell addAudio:wallPost.attachmentLinks[@"audio"] fromStartFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50 + collectionHeight + 5 + 90 + 5, 300, 20)];
}
```